# Python KeyboardInterrupt in Multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading, web-services, keyboard-events, keyboardinterrupt

Can anyone please tell me why the KeyboardInterrupt is not working here? I need to end both of the threads by the press of CTRL+C. The two threads -  Timer thread and Web server thread. Here is the code -

```
import threading
import thread
import time
import urllib2
import httplib

from BaseHTTPServer import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
from SocketServer import ThreadingMixIn
import Queue
import signal
import sys

q = Queue.Queue()
j = Queue.Queue()
h = "threading working!"

class SignalHandler:
   stopper = None    
   def __init__(self,stopper):
      self.stopper = stopper

   def __call__(self, signum, frame):
      self.stopper.set()
      sys.exit(0)

#Timer Thread
class myThread(threading.Thread):
   stopper = None

   def __init__(self, **kwargs):
       self.req = []
       self.stopper = stopper
       for k, v in kwargs.iteritems():
           setattr(self, k, v)
       threading.Thread.__init__(self)

   def run(self):
       while not self.stopper.is_set():
           while self.go:
              try:
                 while True:
                     r = q.get_nowait()
                     self.req.append(r)
              except Queue.Empty, e:
                  pass
              t = threading.Timer(1,self.hello, [h])
              t.start()
              time.sleep(1)

   def hello(self, s):
      print s        
      while self.req:            
         r = self.req.pop()
         print "Client Request >>>>>>>", r                                            
         thread_id = str(threading.currentThread())
         j.put(thread_id)                                   

   def stop(self):
       print "Stopping thread.."
       self.go = False
       try:
           while True:
               q.get_nowait()
           q.task_done()
       except Queue.Empty, e:
           pass     

#Webserver thread
class Handler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

   def do_HEAD(self):
       self.send_response(200)        
       self.send_header("Content type", "text/html")
       self.end_headers()

   def do_GET(self):
       self.do_HEAD()
       req = (self.path, self.client_address, self.command,)        
       q.put(req)     
       self.wfile.write("Thread Info: ")
       self.wfile.write(j.get())                
       return        

class ThreadedHTTPServer(ThreadingMixIn, HTTPServer):
    """Handle requests in a separate thread."""

#main
if __name__ == '__main__':
   stopper = threading.Event()
   handler = SignalHandler(stopper)
   signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handler)  
   server = ThreadedHTTPServer(('localhost', 8080), Handler)
   try:
       timer_thread = myThread(stopper,go=True)        
       timer_thread.start()    
       server_thread = threading.Thread(target=server.serve_forever)
       server_thread.daemon = True
       server_thread.start()        
       print 'Starting server, use <Ctrl-C> to stop'  
   except KeyboardInterrupt, e:
       print "Interrupted"
       q.join()
       j.join()
       timer_thread.stop()
       timer_thread.join()
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation first to help read the code better.

Comment: Done. Hope its better now. Thanks

Comment: Your indentation is still off. Check the code within the class, especially

Comment: I tried to do my best buddy. Sorry if its still off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your instance `myThread` in created with error, must be `stopper=stopper` (keyword arg is expected). Second, code has error, main thread does not wait server thread but immediately go to `join()`s. So, `except` never happens - nothing will be printed. And main bug is in `join()`. Join in Python is not interruptable by signals. So, you must write own join function, which will call original `join()` with timeout (for example, 1 second) but in the infinitive loop. Better is to make join with little timeout and next - `sleep()` - sleep is interruptable. Both in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try to print something next of `except KeyboardInterrupt`, before to call `join()`s, bcz joins are waiting for threads to complete.

Comment: Its not printing it.